# Show multiple lines in one cell of ALV-grid

Tags: abap, alv

I am trying to implement output like on the attached pictur, where I expect one cell to have multiple values

[image]

I want to show it in ALV grid and in future I need to export it in excel document. How?

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Why do you need multiple numbers in 1 cell? It appears like this data would have to be string/text anyways (which you cannot do any calculations on). Generally (not always) that means request is..... let's call it not technically optimal. Is there any reason why splitting cells or showing a cell displaying value count (or total), which you could double click to display the value list?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible because CL_GUI_ALV_GRID is a very simple control, many things are not possible. As said here:

- [Multiple Lines in a Single ALV Grid Cell](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1379894)
- [How to have a Multi-line Display in ALV cell ?](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/905795)
- [How to display multiple lines in a Cell in ALV GRID display](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3292438)
- [Multiple line in one cell(ALV)](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/190946).
- etc.

You have to find a standard workaround (I prefer not talking of the hidden/unsupported feature of merging cells), like a button or a hyperlink in the cell, clicking it displays multiple values (implement it the way you like).